# iterating through elements in different index positions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to make a program that prints a grid from an integer input.

```
def grids(units):
    natural_number = int(input())
    # define size
    x = y = units

    # create empty rows
    grid = []

    # for each row defined by Y, append a list containing X occurrences of "."
    for row in range(y):
        grid.append(list("." * x))

    # fills the first row with natural_number
    for elements in range(units):
        grid[0][elements] = natural_number

    # fills the first column of each row with natural_number
    for elements in range(units):
        grid[elements][0] = natural_number

    return grid

    >>> grids(3)
    >? 5
    [[5, 5, 5], [5, '.', '.'], [5, '.', '.']]
```

for the empty positions in grid[1][1], grid[1][2], grid[2][1], and grid[2][2]

My goal is to make the following outputs

```
''''
    grid[1][1] = grid[1][0] + grid[0][1]
    grid[1][2] = grid[1][1] + grid[0][2]
    grid[2][1] = grid[2][0] + grid[1][1]
    grid[2][2] = grid[2][1] + grid[1][2]

    grid[i][j] = grid[i][j-1] + grid[i-1][j]
''''
```

to fill in for those positions, I came up with the following code.

However, the code returns an error: int object is not iterable.

The code also seems to pose the problem where it will not iterate for grid[1][2] or grid[2][1]

```
for i, j in range(1, units):
    grid[i][j] = grid[i][j - 1] + grid[i - 1][j]
return grid
```

What actions can I take to amend this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take

```
for i, j in range(1,3):
```

And replace it with

```
for i in range(1, 3):
    for j in range(1, 3):
```

I think that will fix your problems